# Should I flag for comment restoration?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, plagiarism, deleted-comments

A user is accusing me of plagiarizing their comment as my answer. We both posted relatively the same comment within 30 seconds. My comment had a functional example though and the OP told me to posted it as an answer. Subsequently I deleted my comment and posted it as an answer. The original commenter is now accusing me of plagiarizing. Should I flag this for a moderator to restore the comment, or how should I handle this?

Question in question: [Dynamically adding x number of days to a date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296705/dynamically-adding-x-number-of-days-to-a-date-in-php/39296815?noredirect=1#comment65930243_39296815)

Comment: Not worth the efforts in my opinion. Just ignore the other user and move on.

Comment: Looks like everything is resolved now, please move on ...

Comment: I should point out that moderators can't undelete comments deleted by normal users, only comments that were deleted by other moderators. We wouldn't be able to undelete your comment, but I believe you can do this if you wanted.

Comment: @BradLarson On the `activity` page under `all actions` then `comments` I only see posted comments, not `deleted`. Is there a separate link/page for the delete ones somewhere?

Comment: If you go to the question itself, do you see your deleted comment or anything that says "1 deleted comment" to the left of the question? This is a direct link to the comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296705/dynamically-adding-x-number-of-days-to-a-date-in-php/39296815?noredirect=1#comment65927133_39296705 which I can see, but not undelete. There has to be a way that you can undelete this yourself.

Comment: @BradLarson Nope, nothing like that.  I can't see my deleted comments. Searching for `delete` brings up 3 references, 2 to the deleted answer, and 1 to delete my answer.

Comment: @BradLarson Non-mods can't see or restore their own deleted comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading the comments, he seems to have retracted his complaint, so you could flag a mod to just delete the whole comment chain as obsolete as you've now resolved the problem between the two of you or you could both just delete your comments yourselves.